# How do I preload or warm up all controls in web application?

Tags: c#, asp.net, webforms, dotnetnuke

I have a large ASP.Net Web Application project. The first load of every page is dramatically slower than subsequent loads.

This is DotNetNuke application with all sorts of authentication as well as many buttons with different functionality on every page, so I can't really warm it up by automating requests to my pages

below, I'm not sure what these temporary files are exactly that get loaded in my output window, as I hit pages for the first time, but I think these are what I want to load ahead of time, before a user hits a page for the first time after application restart.

```
iisexpress.exe' (CLR v4.0.30319: /LM/W3SVC/53/ROOT-2-130941952178711862): Loaded 'C:\Users\user1\AppData\Local\Temp\Temporary ASP.NET Files\vs\98982176\2cd0bb0a\App_Web_pouimq4s.dll
iisexpress.exe' (CLR v4.0.30319: /LM/W3SVC/53/ROOT-2-130941952178711862): Loaded 'C:\Users\user1\AppData\Local\Temp\Temporary ASP.NET Files\vs\98982176\2cd0bb0a\App_Web_zj3nosz2.dll
```

I would like to pre-load, pre-compile, or cache all ascx files in my application before users hit the site. is this possible??

Answer (score 1):

There are various ways to help with this, but the way that DNN Loads things you would have to make sure to visit each page that has a unique module on it.  (Once per module used.  If you use the same module on 5 pages, it would only require one visit.)

The simple route here would be to use an external monitor to simply track the homepage every 10 minutes.  This is what I do with my sites as I have the added benefit of uptime notifications.  I rely on the fact that there is other activity to load up the other modules as needed.

You can tweak the Idle Timeout to prevent the site from shutting down, but a daily recycle usually helps anyway.

Comment: yes, visiting each page with a unique module would work. I am trying to find a simple way to automate this process without having to click everywhere on my site.

Comment: There isn't really a simple way to do this.

Comment: I started using selenium browser automation to click through all pages on my site seems to help